# How to generate android styled javadocs?

Tags: android, javadoc

Is it possible to generate android styled javadocs for my android project (like http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html, instead of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Is it something regarding using of some custom doclet instead of standard doclet? If yes, then which one I have to use?

Answer (score 9):

you could use doclava its the doclet that guice uses and has the same template engine clearsilver(jsilver)..

Answer (score 5):

Apparently it's a custom docklet called DroidDoc. You can look [here](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/?p=63) for a description of the "droid doc" build process.

Comment: I already read that but not succeeded. Could you guide me, if you know, how to accomplish this? It would be better if this may be done using eclipse.